# Where/how gets the PDE Build the target platform plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde, target-platform, pdebuild

i've inherited an Eclipse RCP Project from a colleague who left the company. Along with the project comes the pde build setup, which i don't quite get. During development of the latest release, i need to add another plugin (org.eclipse.compare...). I added it to the  target platform and keept programming. But there are now problems with the build.  The finished product doesn't contain the added plugin .jar. How can i change the build, so that the jar is added? I'm grateful for any hints. Followed a few clues while seraching through the build files, but that turnend up nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the template properties file, which has documentation for properties. Relevant properties is `pluginPath` and especially `baseLocation`. It is located at:

```
[path-to.eclipse]/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_[version]/templates/headless-build/build.properties
```

Consider to copy it and base your build upon it. It might make it easier to maintain your build in the future.